# Problems with setting a root for an ingress in K8S application

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to create an ingress path redirection on an K8S application.

The problem which I'm trying to solve is that in order to access the app the url should include /bvd after the FQDN, and the customer is very picky and doesn't want to have anything after the it.

This is the modified ingress definition, the original one has a path /bvd and is without the app-root annotation: kind: IngressapiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1metadata: name: bvd-ingress - [Pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/uEUMtBJc)

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
name: bvd-ingress
namespace: opsb
uid: c23dfb36-6083-4292-bf65-fdb0042092db
resourceVersion: '8640919'
generation: 15
creationTimestamp: '2023-06-15T10:15:58Z'
labels:
annotations:
ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: 'true'
ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: 'true'
ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: OPSB_AFFINITY_BVD
ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
meta.helm.sh/release-name: opsb-helm
meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: opsb
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /bvd
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: '600'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: '600'
nginx.org/websocket-services: bvd-www
managedFields:
- manager: helm
operation: Update
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
time: '2023-06-15T10:15:58Z'
fieldsType: FieldsV1
fieldsV1:
f:metadata:
f:annotations:
.: {}
f:ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: {}
f:ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: {}
f:ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: {}
f:ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: {}
f:ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: {}
f:ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: {}
f:kubernetes.io/ingress.class: {}
f:meta.helm.sh/release-name: {}
f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {}
f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: {}
f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: {}
f:nginx.org/websocket-services: {}
- manager: dashboard
operation: Update
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
time: '2023-07-06T10:55:49Z'
fieldsType: FieldsV1
fieldsV1:
f:metadata:
f:annotations:
f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: {}
f:spec:
f:rules: {}
spec:
rules:
- host: server.domain
http:
paths:
- path: /
pathType: Prefix
backend:
service:
name: bvd-www
port:
number: 4000
status:
loadBalancer: {}
```

Can someone give me a hint why this is not working, I've been following the documentation but I'm not expert in this subject so I might be doing something totally wrong on missing something else.

Thank you in advance!

I tried to redirect the traffic in the ingress with the [app-root annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/), but it didn't work.

Comment: (a) There are some severe indentation problems with your posted example; please edit your question to correct the syntax (otherwise we can't tell if your problem is anything more than a syntax issue). (b) Please don't link to remote pastebins or other services; include the information necessary to understand your question in the question iteself. (c) In what way is this ingress not working?